# binascii.hexlify() returns binary as String and not Integer

Tags: python, bit-shift

I'm trying to teach myself python and am just generally messing about with it.
I have come across a bit of an issue though.

Basically I'm trying to make something that will turn a string into binary, bit-shift it by x, and then return it to you as a new string.

The best Method I have found to achieve this seems to be binascii.hexlify(str).

The problem that I am getting is that this Method does seem to return the binary representation to me... but as a String??

I cannot call int() on the string, and I've tried multiple combinations of bin(int()) etc. I'm a bit stuck here guys, any help would be appreciated :-)

I know I'm probably going about this in the completely wrong way, but hey. I'm teaching myself so... :-)

See code so far below:

```
import binascii

password = raw_input("Enter your Password")
bits = int(raw_input("Shift By:"))

def getBinary(word):
    return bin(int(binascii.hexlify(word), 16))

def shift(bin, num):
    return bin << num

shift(getBinary(password), bits)
```

Comment: Binary is represented in string form only, if you need to perform some operations on it then convert it to `int` first and finally convert it back to binary using either `bin` or `format`.

Comment: what do you want your shift to do? Shift individual characters in the password? Shift the entire password? If I enter 'hello2', what should happen?

Comment: the point was to turn your word into binary, "bit-shift" the whole binary string by x, then turn the new binary back into a "word" that would more than likely be garbage like "hau938u23jie@@"££"£"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bin()`, `hex()` and so forth are just representations of numbers, in string form. To be able to do bitshifts etc, you keep your value as an integer! Remember, every piece of data within a computer is in binary anyway. Then convert it on output. The default output conversion for an `int` is to print it as a number in base 10, using digits 0-9 ;). Thus try the following

```
import binascii

password = raw_input("Enter your Password: ")
bits = int(raw_input("Shift By: "))

def getBinary(word):
    return int(binascii.hexlify(word), 16)

def shift(bin, num):
    return bin << num

shifted = shift(getBinary(password), bits)
print bin(shifted)
```

Comment: There is no reason to hexlify here. `int(binascii.hexlify(word), 16)` is just `int(word)` and it only works if *word* can be converted to an int and that eliminates most passwords that I tend to use.

Comment: Just to clear things up for everyone, I know this is not a practical encryption. It was simply a random thought that popped into my head and I wondered if I could do it! @tdelaney - The reason to hexlify is to turn the string into binary. I could use binascii.a2b_uu() but I had trouble getting that one to work